# java printing can't figure out why something is printed

Tags: java

Hello I have made a programm that reads from a csv file some data with the scanner class.then below the function is called to extract the information from the read csv file.

```
private void processLine(String inputLine){
    try
    {
    String [] data = inputLine.split(",") ;
    Integer compNumber=checkNumCom(data[0]);
    int scoreLength = data.length-4;
    int scores[] = new int[Darts.scoreNumber];
    String [] temp = new String[scoreLength];
    System.arraycopy(data,4,temp,0,scoreLength );
    if(checkName(data[1]) && compNumber != null && checkStrings(data[2])
            && checkStrings(data[3]) && checkScores(temp) ){
        Name name = new Name(data[1]);
        String country = data[2];
        String level = data[3];
        for(int i=0;i<scoreLength;i++){
            scores[i]= Integer.parseInt(temp[i].trim());

            }
            Darts obj = new Darts(compNumber,name,country,level,scores);
            competitors.addCompetitor(obj);
        }
    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        String error = "Error in: " + inputLine + " index position " + 
                  e.getMessage();
        System.err.println(error);
        }


}
```

this is a sample of the data that the csv contains:

```
108,Paul Martin,France,Novice,3,4,5,2,2
109,Jose Mario Gomez,Portugal,Pro,5,3,5,2,3
```

and this is a function that checks if the name that is read from the file is correct

```
private boolean checkName(String name){
    String[] name1 = name.split(" ");

    if(!name.isEmpty() && name1.length >1 && name1.length<4)
    { 
        return true;

    }

    else
    {
        System.err.println("The competitor name is not acceptable");
        return false;
    }

}
```

even if the data in the csv file are correct this message appears all the time.I have also run the debugger can not figure out.Can somebody help?

[image]

Comment: Can you please print the value of "name" also with you error message so that we can see what is coming in name when getting the error?

Comment: `France,Novice`.. `Portugal,Pro` LOL, you must be from portugal

Comment: I guess a debugger is your friend simply put a breakpoint on `return false` and you will find yourself what's wrong